# Need help installing Mono framework on Raspberry Pi3 running OpenHab2 (openhabian)

Tags: linux, installation, mono, raspberry-pi3, openhab

I'm trying to install Mono on a Raspberry Pi3 that runs OpenHab2 ([openhabian](http://docs.openhab.org/installation/openhabian.html#raspberry-pi)).

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Linux and need some help please.

I followed Mono for RPI instructions from [here](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-lin-raspbian) and unfortunately got into some dependencies-related problems that I don’t know how to solve.

I searched online and found some advice to first install ‘mono-vbnc’ and ‘mono-complete’ :

> ```
> sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc mono-complete
> ```

Unfortunately it also gives some errors:

> openhabian@openHAB2:~$ sudo apt-get install mono-vbnc mono-complete
>   [sudo] password for openhabian: Reading package lists… Done Building
>   dependency tree Reading state information… Done Some packages could
>   not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible
>   situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some
>   required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of
>   Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies: mono-complete :
>   Depends: mono-runtime (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is
>   not going to be installed Depends: mono-runtime-sgen (=
>   5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: mono-utils (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not
>   going to be installed Depends: mono-devel (=
>   5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: mono-mcs (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not
>   going to be installed Depends: mono-roslyn (=
>   5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: mono-csharp-shell (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it
>   is not going to be installed Depends: mono-4.0-gac (=
>   5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it
>   is not going to be installed Depends: monodoc-base (=
>   5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: monodoc-manual (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is
>   not going to be installed Depends: libmono-cil-dev (=
>   5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but it is not going to be installed Depends: ca-certificates-mono (= 5.4.0.201-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1) but
>   it is not going to be installed mono-vbnc : Depends:
>   libmono-microsoft-visualbasic10.0-cil (= 4.6-0xamarin10+raspbian9b1)
>   but it is not going to be installed Depends:
>   libmono-accessibility4.0-cil but it is not going to be installed
>   Depends: libmono-system-configuration4.0-cil but it is not going to be
>   installed Depends: libmono-system-data4.0-cil but it is not going to
>   be installed Depends: libmono-system-design4.0-cil but it is not going
>   to be installed Depends: libmono-system4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but
>   it is not going to be installed Depends:
>   libmono-system-drawing-design4.0-cil but it is not going to be
>   installed Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil but it is not going
>   to be installed Depends: libmono-system-web4.0-cil but it is not going
>   to be installed Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil but it is
>   not going to be installed Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil
>   but it is not going to be installed Depends: libmono-system-xml4.0-cil
>   but it is not going to be installed Depends: mono-runtime (>= 3.0~)
>   but it is not going to be installed Depends: libmono-cecil-vb0.9-cil
>   (>= 2.99) but it is not going to be installed Depends:
>   libmono-corlib4.5-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it is not going to be
>   installed Depends: libmono-system-core4.0-cil (>= 4.0.0~alpha1) but it
>   is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have
>   held broken packages. Could someone please help me install ‘mono
>   framework’ on RPi3 running openhabian?

Thanks in advance!
-Mark

P.S.: Just in case.

```
################# openHAB2 ######################################## 7.05.170509
###############################################################################
##        Ip = 192.168.1.60
##   Release = Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
##    Kernel = Linux 4.9.35-v7+
##  Platform = Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
##    Uptime = 0 day(s). 11:35:3
## CPU Usage = 1.51 % avg over 4 cpu(s)  (4 core(s) x 1 socket(s))
##  CPU Load = 1m: 0.00, 5m: 0.00, 15m: 0.00
##    Memory = Free: 0.40GB (43%), Used: 0.54GB (57%), Total: 0.94GB
##      Swap = Free: 0.09GB (100%), Used: 0.00GB (0%), Total: 0.09GB
##      Root = Free: 26.08GB (92%), Used: 2.00GB (8%), Total: 29.31GB
##   Updates = 0 apt-get updates available.
##  Sessions = 1 sessions
## Processes = 131 running processes of 32768 maximum processes
###############################################################################

                  openHAB 2.1.0-1 (Release Build)
```

Comment: When you are not familiar with Linux, why do you use something like openHAB? I think the Mono page only provides instructions for the default Raspberry systems, which can be the only supported setup.

Comment: Because I'd like to run OpenHab on Raspberry Pi. I need Mono to install another product (NodeLink). And I'd like both OpenHab and NodeLink to run on the same Raspberry Pi.